# Extracting substring from a string in Hive

Tags: string, text, substring, hive, extract

I have a date column. The dates are in format `M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss` or `MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss` or `M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` or `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`
I want to convert these dates in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. How can I achieve it in Hive?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom UDF for this that will read that column, finds the date format that is present in the data and then convert it to required format.
You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse and convert the date column. You can refer to this link for writing custom UDF : [link](http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/08/10/guide-to-writing-hive-udfs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a project in eclipse and write a class like below :

```
package com.custom.udf;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class CustomDateValidator extends UDF{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is a Custom Date Validator class");
    }

    public String evaluate(String dateText) {
        if (null == dateText) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return toDate(dateText);
        }
    }

    public String toDate(String d) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Date dt = new Date(d);
        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        return sf.format(new Date(sdf.format(dt)));
    }

}
```

`evaluate` method needs to be added to udf work.
Add `hive-exec-0.12.0.jar`` in build path.
Create a DateConvertor.jar using eclipse.

Add this jar in hive `add jar <location/DateConvertor.jar>`.
Create function using below command on hive prompt:

```
create temporary function customdate as 'com.custom.udf.CustomDateValidator';
```

Now suppose you wants to use this function for sql command then use below query on hive prompt :

```
select customdate(time) from employee;
```

That's it, this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! It helped

Comment: @Jigy: Accept the answer if it helped